# laravel framework webservice error

Tags: laravel

I am  just doing web service for laravel framework, so below error is displayed, I don't know which type of error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'city' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: SELECT MIN(room_prize)MIN,MAX(room_prize)MAX from `abserve_hotel_rooms` as `ar` JOIN `abserve_hotels` as `h` ON `ar`.`hotel_id` = `h`.`hotel_id` WHERE 1 AND `city` ="madurai" AND `country` ="india")
```

Comment: apply table alias to city field

Answer (score 0):

You forgot table alias to the fields `city` and `country`